# Set theory with selective ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory

Hi,

I know it is possible to construct a model with a non trivial ultrafilter u and I want to show u is such that for all fonction f from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ there is an element of u such that f is constant or strictly monotonic on u (we will say that u is a selective ultrafilter).
I know that we must go from a model of secondary order logic M with comprehension schema and  dependant choice axiom and with set of individuals $\mathscr{P}(N)$ and consider N=M[G] where G is a generic which is a non trivial ultrafilter in N on $\mathbb{N}$ (G exists) but I don't know how to show u is selective.

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: What kind of models are you talking about? The second-order structure of the reals is not a model of set theory.

Comment: In any case, yes, in ZFC one can add a selective ultrafilter by taking a generic ultrafilter in $\mathcal P(\omega)/\mathrm{fin}$, which is apparently the forcing notion you describe. Since every $\omega$-chain in this forcing has a lower bound, there are no new functions $f\colon\omega\to\omega$ (or subsets of $\omega$) in the extension, and for any $f\colon\omega\to\omega$ from the ground model, the set of infinite sets on which $f$ is constant or increasing is dense. This is a simple exercise.

Comment: Assuming CH, it is also possible to construct a selective ultrafilter by a transfinite recursion of length $\omega_1$. (Let $\langle f_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha\lt\omega_1}$ enumerate all functions $\omega\to\omega$. On the $\alpha$-th step, find a pseudointersection to the countably many sets added to $\mathcal{U}$ so far, and shrink it to an infinite set on which $f_\alpha$ is either constant or strictly increasing.)


Comment: Thanks for your reply and your attention, 

I was not very clear in my first post I didn't speak about a model of ZFC but M is a model of second order with comprehension schema. I add to M in M[G] a non trivial ultrafilter. I showed following your indication that the set of infinite sets in $\mathbb{N}$ on which f is constant or increasing is dense then G cuts this set and I conclude that there is an element of the generic G on which f is constant or strictly increasing.

But I don't know justify why f is in M, it is not clear for me.

Thanks.

Comment: I precise that it is necessary to show that f is in M to conclude (but how yet ?) that D(f) is in M (where D(f) is the set of all infinite sets of $\mathbb{N}$ on which f is bounded or strictly increasing), then G meets D(f) because  G is a generic in M thus it meets all the dense set in M. 

Comment: I'm not familiar with your set-up, but the argument should be similar as in ZFC. Look up the subsection "Distributivity" (p. 228) of chapter 15 of Jech's Set Theory, The Third Millenium Edition. Your forcing is $\omega$-closed.

Comment: Since the question wasn't specific about the intended notion of forcing, I suspect the OP might be thinking about the set of infinite subsets of $\omega$ ordered by inclusion, which is not literally $\omega$-closed.  But forcing with it is equivalent to forcing with its separative quotient, mentioned in Emil's second comment, and obtained by identifying any two sets whose symmetric difference is finite.  This quotient is $\omega$-closed, and therefore, as Emil wrote, the forcing adds no new functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$.